# MapStruct - How to ignore the unnecessary methods/non-getter-setter methods in the POJO

Tags: java, list, mapping, pojo, mapstruct

Below is the POJO:

```
public class TransferObjectListTO {

    private List<A> transferList;

    public List<A> getTransferList() {
        return transferList;
    }

    public void setList(List<A> transferList) {
        this.transferList= transferList;
    }

    public List<A> getList() {
        return getTransferList();
    }

    public void incrementList(List<A> transferList) {
        getTransferList().addAll(transferList);
    }

}
```

It has a kind of adder method -

> incrementList

along with duplicate to getter method -

> getList

The Mapstruct generated code has below unnecessary stuff, which adds list, one more time of source type:

```
if ( targetTypeTransferObjectListTO.getList() != null ) {
    List sourceTypeList = sourceTypeTransferObjectListTO.getList();
    if ( sourceTypeList != null ) {
        targetTypeTransferObjectListTO.getList().addAll( sourceTypeList );
    }
}
```

We cannot remove these methods - `incrementList() and getList()` in above POJO because it is used in many places. Now, how can we ignore these methods when mapstruct is generating implementation for mapping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways that you can achieve what you are looking for. The problem is only with the `getList()` method, the `incrementList()` is already ignored by MapStruct.

#### Ignore the mapping

If you don't have a lot of POJOs that have this pattern and you have few mappers that use this you can just add

```
@Mapping(target = "list", ignore = true)
```

#### Write your own `AccessorNamingStrategy`

In case you have a lot of POJOs and a lot of mappers then I would suggest you to write your own custom `AccessorNamingStrategy` that would mark the `getList()` method as `OTHER` method.

```
public class CustomAccessorNamingStrategy extends DefaultAccessorNamingStrategy {

    @Override
    public boolean isGetterMethod(ExecutableElement method) {
        if (method.getSimpleName().toString().equals("getList")) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return super.isGetterMethod(method);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a very good entry point, but it lacks the information about how to use that custom AccessorNamingStrategy. I would add the following documentation:
https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_custom_accessor_naming_strategy
https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-spi-accessor-naming